# How to show circled portion of a image in beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics

[image]

I want to show only a circled portion of the image in my slide.

[image]

I know that it can be possible by editing the image as circled image. But, I want to know whether LaTeX has this feature or not.

Comment: You could clip the portion with the Ti*k*Z command `\clip`.

Comment: @marmot would you give a example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How to clip a picture?}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) ellipse (3 and 3);
% \clip (0,0) rectangle +(5,3); for crop in rectangle
% \clip (0,0) circle (3); for crop in circle
\node at (0.8,-3) {\includegraphics{Logo3.png}}; %<-you'll need to adjust these
% coordinates, I do not have your original picture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention that you may want to play with the scale of the graphics.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How to clip a picture?}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) ellipse (3 and 2.8);
\node at (0.62,-3) {\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Logo3.png}}; %<-you'll need to adjust these
% coordinates, I do not have your original picture
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answer fulfill my requirements. If you describe your answer it is well for me and others to understand.

Comment: describe `scale=0.75`, is it zooming/positioning?

Comment: @alhelal It just means it scales the picture to 75% of its original size, i.e. it's zooming out .

Comment: can you check https://paste.ubuntu.com/=gNkXZV9rYg/ this code? same issue

Comment: how to measure the co-ordinate of the image in `\node at (x, y)`?

Comment: @alhelal I do not understand the question? Do you mean the size of the picture? In this case you can use `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{...}`. These things are all written in the [manual of the graphicx package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).